# Why doesn't a = 6 in the middle of a sea of operations assign 6 into a? (C programming)

Tags: c

I'm currently learning the basics of C programming language, but I can't seem to figure out how C understands the following code of operators. Below is the program, which prints "1, 1, 3, 0", while I think it should print "1, 1, 6, 0".

I've tried tweaking the line about y with the hypothesis that C language reads from the start, and once it saw !two, which is one, and the || operator, it said to itself, "Ah, whatever comes after || doesn't matter," and didn't assign 6 to one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int one = 3, two = 1, x, y;

    x = !!one && ((two = 0) != 0) || 3;
    y = !two || ((one = 6) != 0) && !3;

    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d", x, y, one, two);

}
```

So, I tried removing the ! in !two, switching the order around ||, which proved my hypothesis. However, when I switched ((one = 6) != 0) and !3, one is printed as 6. Now, I got no bright ideas as to how this happens.

Comment: Because `&&` and `||` are sequence points and if short circuiting is applied, the right hand side will never be evaluated.

Comment: When I switch `((one = 6) != 0)` and `!3` in your code, then `one` is printed as `3`, as I would expect. Please post the exact code that gives the unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
x = !!one && ((two = 0) != 0) || 3;
```

first `!!one` evaluated i.e first `!one` which is `0` and then again `!0` which is `1` i.e `true`, next is logical AND `&&` operator and ***`&&` property is that if first operand is `true` then only check second operand***, which is correct in our case.

```
 x = !!one && ((two = 0) != 0) || 3;
        |      |              |
       true     --------------
       (1)           |
                  solve this now
```

second operand of `&&` is `((two = 0) != 0)` which first makes `two` as `0`(zero) and then `0!=0` which is false. Now it looks like

```
x = true && false || 3
     |        |
      --------
         |
       false     ||  3   <= logical OR property is if 1st operand is false then need to check second operand.
x = false || true
x = 1
```

So after this expression `x=1` and `two=0`.

Next, below expression

```
y = !two || ((one = 6) != 0) && !3;
```

First `!two` solved first i.e `!0` i.e `1` that is `true` and logical OR `||` operator properties is that ***if first operand is true then second operands is not evaluated*** due to short circuiting. Hence it becomes

```
y = 1;
```

So after this expression
`x=1` `two=0` and `y=1` rest all unchanged i.e `one` will be its initial value which is `3`. So this

```
printf("%d, %d, %d, %d", x, y, one, two);
```

prints `1, 1, 3, 0`

**Side note**, truth table of **logical OR** `||` operator

```
A  B   A||B
------------
0  0    0
0  1    1   => If 1st operand is zero, need to evaluate 2nd operand because 2nd operand may be 0 or 1
1  0    1   => if first operand is 1(true), result is always going to true, hence don't evaluate second operand 
1  1    1
```

Truth table of **logical AND** `&&` operator is

```
    A  B   A&&B
    ------------
    0  0    0
    0  1    0   => If 1st operand is zero, result is always going to false, so need not to evaluate 2nd operand.
    1  0    0   => if first operand is 1(true), Need to evaluate 2nd operand because 2nd operand may be 0 or 1.
    1  1    1
```